# Functional composition of member function predicates

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, higher-order-functions

In C++11, it is en vogue to use small lambda expressions to produce ad-hoc predicates. However, sometimes it's fun to create predicates in a functional, "point-free" way. That way, no function bodies need to be inspected, the code is mildly self-documenting, and it's a great icebreaker at parties.

Suppose I have a `std::vector<std::vector<int>> v`, and I want to remove all the empty inner vectors. The lambda-style `remove_if` call might look like this:

```
std::remove_if(v.begin(),
               v.end(),
               [](std::vector<int> const & w) -> bool { return w.empty(); });
```

This is verbose and redundant. The point-free approach uses `std::mem_fn`:

```
std::remove_if(v.begin(),
               v.end(),
               std::mem_fn(&std::vector<int>::empty));
```

This works fine. But now the problem: Suppose I want to further compose this predicate, say by negating it. In the lambda this would be a trivial change. But for the functional notation, we *would* like to use the library function `std::not1` to produce a `unary_negate` wrapper.

However, the obvious `std::not1(std::mem_fn(&std::vector<int>::empty))` does not compile. The problem appears to be that the result type of `std::mem_fn` defines its `argument_type` member type as a *pointer* to the class, not a reference; cf. 20.8.10/2:

> The simple call wrapper shall define two nested types named `argument_type` and `result_type` as synonyms for `cv T*` and `Ret`, respectively, when `pm` is a pointer to member function with cv-qualifier `cv` and taking no arguments, where `Ret` is pm’s return type.

This breaks the composability with `std::not1`.

I have written this type mangling work-around which strips the unwanted pointer:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct result_type_mangler : T
{
    using argument_type = typename std::remove_pointer<typename T::argument_type>::type;
    result_type_mangler(T t) : T(t) { }
};

template <typename T>
result_type_mangler<T> mangle(T t)
{
    return result_type_mangler<T>(t);
}
```

Now I can compose the predicates:

```
std::not1(mangle(std::mem_fn(&std::vector<int>::empty)))
```

Is this a legitimate work-around? Can member function predicates be composed in an easier way? And why is the member function wrapper's `argument_type` defined in such a weird way?

Comment: Note: `bind` also doesn't work: `std::not1(std::bind(&std::vector<int>::empty, std::placeholders::_1))`

Comment: Those parties sound fun!

Answer (score 3):

The verbosity of C++14 generic lambdas should be much lower than `std::mem_fun`

```
std::remove_if(v.begin(),
               v.end(),
               [](auto const & w) { return w.empty(); });
```

If you want to remove non-empty vectors, you can also do something like

```
std::function<bool(std::vector<int>)> is_empty = [](auto const & w) { return w.empty(); }; 
std::remove_if(v.begin(),
               v.end(),
               std::not1(is_empty));
```

Oh and the `-> bool` in your question is already superfluous in C++11 for single-line lambdas. Generic lambdas are currently supported by Clang >= 3.4, GCC 4.9 and MSVC 2013 November CTP.

I think Scott Meyers even has an Item "Prefer lambdas over bind" in his upcoming book Effective C++11/14.

Answer (score 2):

I think your way works, but there are other solutions:

In C++98, there is actually an `std::mem_fun_ref` function.
In C++11, there is the `std::ref` and `std::cref` functions.

```
// VS2012 doesn't have uniform initialization, so this is me being lazy
int a1 [] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ;
int a2 [] = {6, 7, 8} ;

std::vector <int> v1 (std::begin (a1), std::end (a1)) ;
std::vector <int> v2 ;
std::vector <int> v3 (std::begin (a2), std::end (a2)) ;

std::vector <std::vector <int> > vv ;
vv.push_back (v1) ;
vv.push_back (v2) ;
vv.push_back (v3) ;

std::cout << vv.size () << std::endl ;

auto end = std::remove_if (std::begin (vv), std::end (vv), std::not1 (std::cref (&std::vector<int>::empty))) ;
vv.erase (end, std::end (vv)) ;

std::cout << vv.size () << std::endl ;
```

**Update**
It seems that using `std::cref` only works on Visual Studio. `std::mem_fun_ref` is a portable but deprecated solution. Therefore, I would say that your way is the best way out of these three solutions.

Comment: That sounded interesting, but I can't reproduce that. With gcc, `std::cref(&std::vector<int>::empty)` is an error, [e.g. see here](http://ideone.com/gRdrvw). Maybe a VS weirdness?

Comment: I looked over the `reference_wrapper` class implementation is Visual Studio 2012. It uses, what I believe is a [universal reference](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) in its constructor. I don't own a copy of the standard, but I'm assuming you're correct and that this is VS weirdness. `std::mem_fun_ref` seems to work, but that's a deprecated solution.